# Why do I need to add classpath in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I tried to add this class to my code:

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Request;
import org.junit.runner.Result;

public class SingleJUnitTestRunner {
    public static void main(String... args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String[] classAndMethod = args[0].split("#");
        Request request = Request.method(Class.forName(classAndMethod[0]),
                classAndMethod[1]);

        Result result = new JUnitCore().run(request);
        System.exit(result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Then I got this error:

[image]

Even though my *Gradle* includes *JUnit* 4.12

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
```

How can I fix this?
What does "adding to class path" mean? I used to see it in *Eclipse*. Not in *IntelliJ*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
```

instead of:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
```

Comment: i'll try/ but what's is the class path?

Comment: see there are 4 things:
(1) src/main/java
(2) src/main/resources
(3) src/test/java
(4) src/test/resources:::

So, what my understanding is: you have added a class in src/main/java and in your gradle you have defined testCompile. So, gradle will add the junit dependency in src/test/java and not in src/main/java while if you use 'compile' instead of 'testCompile' it will use dependency in src/main/java and hence it wont ask you for adding classpath because junit jar will be already there while using 'compile'

Comment: Did you get the concept?

Answer (score 1):

If your project in IntelliJ is setup as a Gradle project, the classpath should be in sync with your gradle file. You can configure IntelliJ dependencies at File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> Plus Button (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ab6r.png)

The classpath is used by the compiler. It needs to know where to find JUnitCore so it can compile.